# Can't add object to Django's Many-To-Many Field

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, many-to-many

I'm trying to make app with Many-To-Many Field. And I write it and wont to try it. So, I started shell and make some objects and I get this error.

```
>>> mzz.controlsOrganization.add(org1, org2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/fdobrovolny/virtualenv/first/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 848, in __get__
through=self.field.rel.through,
  File "/home/fdobrovolny/virtualenv/first/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 538, in __init__
(instance, source_field_name))
ValueError: "<MZZ: TEST 1>" needs to have a value for field "mzz" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

MZZ class:

```
class MZZ(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name.short_decription = u'Název MZZ'
    ident = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField()
    active.boolean = True
    kind = models.ForeignKey(kind)
    deliveryDate = models.DateField()
    stateAfterDelivery = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dateOfCommissioning = models.DateField()
    prescribedParameters = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    responsibleStaff = models.ForeignKey(User)
    dateOfManufacture = models.DateField()
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(organization, related_name='manufacturer')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    serialNumber = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    frequencyOfControls = models.ForeignKey(controls_frequency)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    methodOfControls = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    controlsOrganization = models.ManyToManyField(organization, related_name='controlsOrganization')
    servisOrganization = models.ManyToManyField(organization, related_name='servisOrganization')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name'
```

organization class:

```
class organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    telephoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Can please somebody help me?

Comment: As a side note, you might want to reconsider your use of `related_name`. It doesn't really make sense to use the same name as the field. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) for more details on the semantics of this name.

Comment: Thanks to note. I had it previously solved by three foreign Key. A django does not support more than one forgeinkey in the table pointing to the same table (organization), but this can be solved by "related_name". I do not know if this must be with Many-To-ManyField.

Comment: You should definitely use `related_name`, I was just suggesting you use more informative names that indicate that it's a collection of `MZZ's` being pointed to. For example, `manufacturer_mzz_set`, `controls_mzz_set`, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to create the MZZ object and save() it  first and then add an organization.

```
mzz = MZZ()  # create 
mzz.save()   # save()

o = organization()
o.save()

m.organization.add(o)  # add(o)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Thanks, I spent a lot of time on it. Thanks a lot.